# Understanding of classification report generated from my model

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to build a model and train it and predict my trained model and see its accuracy and generate a classification report.
I do not understand why is my no accident precision is zero. Whereas I provided 286  images for accident and 3249 for no accident. I was hoping that the model will have high precision for no accident but its opposite, could someone please tell me what could be the issue?

Does this happen because of the very unbiased dataset? or the model I am using is not good? Could someone please post your opinion?

code

```
X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)

X.shape 
(3535, 224, 224, 3)

y.shape 
(3535,)

np.unique(y)
array(['accident', 'noaccident'], dtype=object)

Frequency of unique values of the said array:
[['accident' 'noaccident']
[286 3249]]

lb = LabelBinarizer()
labels = lb.fit_transform(y)

np.unique(labels)
array([0, 1])            ---> two classes are there


(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(X, labels,
    test_size=0.20, stratify=labels, random_state=42)

trainAug = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=30,
    zoom_range=0.15,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.15,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode="nearest")

valAug = ImageDataGenerator()

mean = np.array([123.68, 116.779, 103.939], dtype="float32")
trainAug.mean = mean
valAug.mean = mean

baseModel = ResNet50(weights="imagenet", include_top=False,
    input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))

headModel = baseModel.output
headModel = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(7, 7))(headModel)
headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(512, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(len(lb.classes_), activation="softmax")(headModel)

model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)

for layer in baseModel.layers:
    layer.trainable = False


print("[INFO] compiling model...")
opt = SGD(lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9, decay=1e-4 / 50)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
    metrics=["accuracy"])

print("[INFO] training head...")
H = model.fit(
    x=trainAug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=32),
    steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // 32,
    validation_data=valAug.flow(testX, testY),
    validation_steps=len(testX) // 32,
    epochs= 50)

print("[INFO] evaluating network...")
predictions = model.predict(x=testX.astype("float32"), batch_size=32)


print(classification_report(testY.argmax(axis=1),
    predictions.argmax(axis=1), target_names=lb.classes_))


Output:

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

     accident       1.00      0.57      0.72       707
   noaccident       0.00      0.00      0.00         0

    accuracy                           0.57       707
   macro avg       0.50      0.28      0.36       707
weighted avg       1.00      0.57      0.72       707
```

Comment: can you provide samples of test and train data?

Comment: Those are frames extracted from a video.

Comment: Yes but what are the shapes? especially the test data.

Comment: please check the X.shape and y.shape updated

Comment: whats the shape of `textY` again? y is a 1D vector right? So `textY` is 1D as well?

Comment: in train test split i am getting (707, 1)  for testY

Comment: Ah ok. so it's still (n,1) right? So why are you doing `testY.argmax(axis=1)` in classification report. Can you just use `testY` ? Let me know if that fixed it. If yes ill post it as an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228493/discussion-between-ksp-and-akshay-sehgal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using -

```
print(classification_report(testY, predictions.argmax(axis=1), target_names=lb.classes_))
```

`textY` is an already (n,1) shaped vector with 0,1 classes and will always give same value for `testY.argmax(axis=1)`, which is equal to `0`. That's why your first class has a precision of 1 while the second has a precision of 0. Because you have predicted all 0s correctly.

`predictions.argmax(axis=1)` is a (n,2) shaped vector, has probability values for class 0 and class 1. You will have to convert it to its classes by taking the argmax so don't change that.